# How to copy in clipboard only one DIV from multiple divs using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

How to copy text from a div to clipboard.
What I can do then only get one data in clipboard .

```
<div id="div1">Text To Copy</div>
<div id="div2">Text To Copy</div>
<div id="div3">Text To Copy</div>
<div id="div4">Text To Copy</div>

<script>
   function copyDivToClipboard() {
      var range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNode(document.getElementById("e.target(id)"));
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); // clear current selection
      window.getSelection().addRange(range); // to select text
      document.execCommand("copy");
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();// to deselect
     }
</script>
```

Comment: do you want to copy when clicking on text in particular `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also stuck in same kind of problem. I found the solution.
If you want to show the `message` in the same `div` do this, just try

```js
function copyDivToClipboard(id) {
  var range = document.createRange();
  oldvalue = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
  
  range.selectNode(document.getElementById(id));
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); // clear current selection
  window.getSelection().addRange(range); // to select text
  document.execCommand("copy");
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();// to deselect
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "Text Copied";
  setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = oldvalue }, 2000); //you can change the time 
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" onclick="copyDivToClipboard(this.id);">Text To Copy div1</div>
<div id="div2" onclick="copyDivToClipboard(this.id);">Text To Copy div2</div>
<div id="div3" onclick="copyDivToClipboard(this.id);">Text To Copy div3</div>
<div id="div4" onclick="copyDivToClipboard(this.id);">Text To Copy div4</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try it this way. Call the function on `onclick` event

```js
function copyDivToClipboard(id) {
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(document.getElementById(id));
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); // clear current selection
  window.getSelection().addRange(range); // to select text
  document.execCommand("copy");
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();// to deselect
  alert("Text Copied: "+range);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" onclick="copyDivToClipboard(this.id);">Text To Copy div1</div>
<div id="div2" onclick="copyDivToClipboard(this.id);">Text To Copy div2</div>
<div id="div3" onclick="copyDivToClipboard(this.id);">Text To Copy div3</div>
<div id="div4" onclick="copyDivToClipboard(this.id);">Text To Copy div4</div>
```

Comment: If i want change div content for some second with some custom message like Text Copy not like alert msg then how can I do this task can you suggest me somethings

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: After div content copy I want user get some msg you are copy the text in your code this msg part already have as alert msg I want to user get this msg in same div with replace old text for some second after some time later div text visible again

Comment: can you post a different question for this? or modify this question adding this part

Comment: Ok I am try to modify

Comment: function copyDivToClipboard(id) {
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(document.getElementById(id));
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); // clear current selection
  window.getSelection().addRange(range); // to select text
  document.execCommand("copy");
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();// to deselect
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "Copied";
}

last line of text append but I want this visible for only short time after some time its hide

Comment: check, I have added another answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this if you are using `jQuery`

```js
$("div").click(function(e){
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(document.getElementById(e.target.id));
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); // clear current selection
  window.getSelection().addRange(range); // to select text
  document.execCommand("copy");
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();// to deselect
  console.log("Text Copied: "+range);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">Text To Copy1</div>
<div id="div2">Text To Copy2</div>
<div id="div3">Text To Copy3</div>
<div id="div4">Text To Copy4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I think shirshak007 answered. But I would like to share an alternative code snippet to it.**

```
<script>

function CopyToClipboard(id) {
    var copyBoxElement = document.getElementById(id);
    copyBoxElement.contenteditable = true;
    copyBoxElement.focus();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    copyBoxElement.contenteditable = false;

    alert("Text has been copied :  " +  copyBoxElement.innerHTML)
}

</script>



<div id="div1"  onclick="CopyToClipboard(this.id)">Codebay</div> 
<div id="div2"  onclick="CopyToClipboard(this.id)">Software</div>
```

Comment: Thanks its also work can you tell me I want to user get this msg in same div with replace old text for some short time after some time old div text visible again

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? Or can you share the question in a new section?